# Trying to create an executable Python script but errors with "...version of %1 is not compatible..."

Tags: shell, python-2.7, exe

So I'm just learning how to create Python packages and I've written a script into my package that reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "This is a script for printing this!
```

and after packaging it with `python setup.py sdist' and installing it with`python setup.py install`, the script is successfully **`installed into my .../python27/scripts`** directory but running the script results in an **error**:

```
Program 'practicescript.exe' failed to execute: 
  This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of 
  Windows you are running. Check your computer's system information to 
  see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the 
  program, and then contact the software publisher.
```

I tried initially with a 32 bit version of Python2 and then switched to a 64 bit version (my computer is 64 bit) but still with no success.